# How to write in a DataGridView from a different class

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a Form1, with a DataGridView2 in it.

I want to use this DataGridView in a different class (Class1), that will insert in my DataGridView some data that I take from a database. (In this Class1 I have the connection to this database).
The code of my Class1, for the extraction of the data from the DB is:

```
var context = new dbGAPEntities();
BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
bi.DataSource = context.clienti.ToList();
dataGridView2.DataSource = bi;
dataGridView2.Refresh();
```

But I can't do this because, in this class, I don't have  dataGridView2.
How can I do to reference in my class1, the DataGridView  from Form1?

I hope that my problem is clear.

I tried other questions related to this problem, but I have not been of any help.

Comment: Your Business Logic Layer (or Data Access Layer, or Service Layer) is not aware of UI layer and in fact they don't need to be aware of that. The UI Layer just pass data to those layers and use the results. And also The BLL, just get input data or return output data and doesn't have any idea about who wants to use data and how the data is going to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Class1.BindGridDataSource(this.dataGridView2);
    }
}

public static class Class1
{
    public static void BindGridDataSource(DataGridView grid)
    {
        // Bind grid to data source
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be to pass you DataGridView as a ref parameter. However I recommend to pay close attention to your architecture, User interface (DataGridView) shouldn't be referenced in your data access layer.

```
Private void GridBind(ref DataGridView dgv){
  var context = new dbGAPEntities();
  BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
  bi.DataSource = context.clienti.ToList();
  dgv.DataSource = bi;
  dgv.Refresh();

}
```

You can perform GridBind method doing something like that:

```
GridBind(ref DataGridView1);
GridBind(ref DataGridView2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a function to your class that fills the DataGridView like this:

```
public void FillDataGridView(DataGridView dgv)
{
    var context = new dbGAPEntities();
    BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
    bi.DataSource = context.clienti.ToList();
    dgv.DataSource = bi;
    dgv.Refresh();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
class1.FillDataGridView(this.DataGridView2);
```

Or you can add a property to your class like this:

```
public BindingSource BindSrc
{
    get
    {
        var context = new dbGAPEntities();
        BindingSource bi = new BindingSource();
        bi.DataSource = context.clienti.ToList();
        return bi;
    }
}
```

And in your Form:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = class1.BindSrc;
dataGridView2.Refresh();
```